# Can I link to a YouTube thumbnail preview animation from about a week ago?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I hover my mouse over a YouTube thumbnail, a 3-second video preview is animated in a GIF-like format.
I know how to get the link but it dies within a day.. Is it possible to get a more long term link?

To get the temp URL:

-1 Search up the video on youtube, then copy the video url unique identifier. The identifier for this example was "XI7bgHIFlJA"

[image]

-2 Go back to the search results, view page source, press "Ctrl+F", 
search the unique identifier, and press the up button to search from from the bottom of the page first. 
Copy thaat url to a notepad.

[image]

-3 replace "\u0026" with the symbol "&".

[image]

-and thats it, you have working, but temporary link.

[image]
You can also download the file with a firefox extension called "Media download helper" by fbion if you 
go into the user settings of that app and enable youtube for the "auto catch image". That way, 
every-time you hover over a video that has a animation, it gets captured. -probably a low privacy addon ....

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get a more permanent link? I have used this method before and the URL link breaks after about a day.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get link to video preview on the thumbnails \[ Youtube \]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970110/get-link-to-video-preview-on-the-thumbnails-youtube)