# How to wait for a promise inside an each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, youtube, each

New to promises - trying to work out the logic.

I'm trying to grab youtube preview thumbnails automatically like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970110/get-link-to-video-preview-on-the-thumbnails-youtube) advises:

```
const youtubeAnimation = id => {
    return fetch(
        `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${id}&sp=QgIIAQ%253D%253D`,
        { headers: {} }
    )
        .then(r => r.text())
        .then(html => {
            const found = html.match(
                new RegExp(`["|']https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/${id}/(.*?)["|']`)
            );
            if (found) {
                try {
                    const url = JSON.parse(found[0]);
                    return url;
                } catch (e) {}
            }
            throw "not found";
        })
        .catch(e => {
            return false;
        });
};
```

I store the youtube ID in the video attribute's container, and then do this which works well for a single video on the page:

```
youtubeAnimation($('.video').attr('youtube')).then(function (value) {
    $('<img class="videopreview" src="' + value + '">').insertBefore($('.video'));
});
```

But I need to be able to run this with a variable number of `$('.video')` elements on the page. I've tried putting it in an each loop:

```
$(".video").each(function () {
    youtubeAnimation($(this).attr('youtube')).then(function (value) {
        $('<img class="videopreview" src="' + value + '">').insertBefore($(this));
    });
});
```

But all this does is add the preview thumbnail to the last `$('.video')` element. When testing with console.log I can see that all preview images are being discovered, but that only the last image is applied to the last element. I need to somehow pause the `each` loop until `youtubeAnimation` does its thing, before proceeding to the next element.

What are the additional steps required to make this all work? And also, what is the reason that answer gave `youtubeAnimation` as a const, and not a function?

Comment: try `.then((value) =>` instead of `.then(function (value) {` - so `this` is correct

Comment: by the way, you can't wait for promises inside a .each or .forEach in the way you may think, i.e. you can't use .forEach/.each to execute a series of asynchronous tasks one after the other - just wanted to clarify that your issue isn't waiting for promises, it's the `this` inside the `.then` is not what you expected

Comment: @JaromandaX Wow it worked! TIL about arrow functions. Grateful for the insight, I'm off to research. If the problem was `this`, shouldn't it also work to use a regular function and store `$(this)` in a variable, then call it inside the promise? It doesn't work when I try that.

Comment: did you store $(this) like `.each(function (value) { var $this = $(this); youtubeAnimation(... etc`

Comment: @JaromandaX close but I did not include `var` or `value` there. It was `.each(function () { this = $(this)...`. I can't check to confirm if that fixes it because I've been rate limited now. But theoretically, this should be another way to solve this issue?

Comment: you can't assign `this` and you NEED to use var/let/const, don't use a global

Comment: Oops yes - I was simplifying too much for the sake of clarity, the variable was actually something else, not literally `this`. But noted about local/global

Answer (score 0):

One option that I would try is:

```js
$(".video").each(async () => {
  const animation = await youtubeAnimation($(this).attr('youtube'));
  $('<img class="videopreview" src="' + value + '">').insertBefore($(this));
  
});
```

It utilizes arrow function to preserve `this` and async/await to make the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this too. I think `value` in line 3 was meant to be `animation`? But when I do that, I get "Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null".

Comment: this would work if you `.each(async function() {` because the `this` you want is the `this` in the `.each` callback ... the `this` in this code would NOT be correct